# Writing a word macro to organize chat logs

Tags: regex, vba, replace, ms-word

I need some help writing a word macro to organize some chat logs. What I want is to eliminate repeated consecutive occurrences of names, regardless of timestamp. Besides this, each person will be using their own formatting style (font, font color, etc.). *Edit: the raw logs have no formatting (i.e. specific fonts, font color ,etc.). I want the macro to automatically add a specific (already existent) word style to each user.*

So, what I have is:

```
[12:40] Steve: this is an example text.
[12:41] Steve: this is another example text.
[12:41] Steve: this is yet another example text.
[12:45] Bob: some more text.
[12:46] Bob: even more text.
[12:47] Steve: yadda yadda yadda.
```

The expected output would be:

```
[12:40] Steve: *style1*this is an example text.
this is another example text.
this is yet another example text.*/style1*
[12:45] Bob: *style2*some more text.
even more text.*/style2*
[12:47] Steve: *style1*yadda yadda yadda.*style1*
```

As of now, unfortunately, I know next to nothing of VBA for Applications. I was thinking of maybe searching for the names by a regex pattern and assigning them to a variable, comparing each match to the previous and, if they're equal, deleting the latter. The problem is I'm not fluent in VBA, so I don't know how to do what I want.

So far, all I've got is this:

```
Sub Organize()

    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim names As MatchCollection, name As Match
    re.Pattern = "\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\] [a-zA-Z]{1,20}:"
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Global = True
    Set names = re.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)

    For Each name In names
    'This is where I get lost
    Next name   
End Sub
```

So, in the interest of solving this problem and me learning some VBA, could I get some help?

EDIT: the question has been edited to better reflect what I want the macro to do.

Comment: looking at first set from your log- is each line a separate paragraph in your DOC document?

Comment: @KazJaw Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line in your log is a separate paragraph I would do it without Regex but with `.Find object` feature. The following code is working find for the sample data you provided.

```
Sub qTest()
    Dim PAR As Paragraph
    Dim PrevName As String

    For Each PAR In ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs
        PAR.Range.Select    'highlight current paragraph
            'find name in paragraph
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "\]*\:"
                .Execute
            End With
            If Selection.Text = PrevName Then
                'extend region for the whole paragraph
                'end delete it
                ActiveDocument.Range(PAR.Range.Start, Selection.End + 1).Delete
            Else
                PrevName = Selection.Text
                Debug.Print PrevName
            End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, so that part is tackled. But what about styles? Assuming there are only two different persons in the same log, I'd like each to have their own text style, *excluding* the names and timestamps themselves (i.e everything before the colon, colon inclusive). Say, first person using style1 and second person using style2, like the expected output I posted in the question.